# How to add a Maven catalog that contains all common application templates?

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I would like to be able to select Maven archetypes for commonly used Spring boot applications, Spring MVC and Web Services like Jersey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For developing Spring Boot application, you can go through this link: [Developing your first Spring Boot application](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html)

A good tutorial is also here: [Spring Boot : Running Spring MVC Application](http://javabeat.net/spring-boot-spring-mvc/)

### Traditional `pom.xml` for spring boot is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <!-- Your own application should inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-samples</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-sample-traditional</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Spring Boot Traditional Sample</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Traditional Sample</description>
    <url>http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/</url>
    <organization>
        <name>Pivotal Software, Inc.</name>
        <url>http://www.spring.io</url>
    </organization>
    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
        <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Provided (for embedded war support) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Hello @SkyWalker, Thanks for the response. While this helps a bit, this is not quite what I was looking for. I needed to have a collection of archetypes added to Mavan catalog. Please let me know if you know.